# How can I get a file pointer ( FILE* ) of known file in a specific path?

Tags: c, linux, file, unix

to read/write a file i need file pointer in language C in Unix environment.
I know a file name and path, but how to get file pointer using its name and path.

Comment: [`fopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

Comment: Because you are on unix env, do "man fopen"

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w");
```

Answer (score 1):

Import the standard input/output header like so

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

And then create a pointer for the file you want to open.

```
FILE * file_pointer;
file_pointer = fopen ("[path to file]","w");
fclose(file_pointer);
```

NOTE: Specify whole path to file if it is not in the same directory as your source file.
Dont forget to close the file after you have done the operations you need

Answer (score 0):

According to the post from ssmithstone:

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE * pFile;
/* open file and check if was successful */ 
if ((pFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "w")) == NULL)
{
/* couldn't open file; do some error handling if u want */
}
else
{
/* do s.th. */
/* close file */
fclose(pFile);
}
```

In this case `w` means writing. For other options check the link posted by Yu Hao.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are new in C programming, I've written a `C` program for you, you can analyse it and I believe it will be definitely helpful to you.

```
#define size 50
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    char name[size]; 
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("your_file.txt","w");
    printf("Please enter your first name\n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    fprintf(file,"%s",name);
    fclose(file); 
    return 0; 
}
```

**Details:**

- In line 7 the second parameter **`w`** is used as file open mode - with write privileges.
- The file pointer is used to create  / open a file with name "**your_file.txt**".
- function `fprintf()` is same as `printf()` function but it writes not on console but to your file.
- finally we need to close the file writing operations thus we use `fclose()` function

---

**Update:**

To specify your path you can write your file path with your filename.fileextension
for example: You can write it as

```
file = fopen("/home/depthgr8/Desktop/your_file.txt","w");
```

This will create your_file.txt in given path if your path exists otherwise it will throw a runtime exception - segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: "So where does the path go?" Add a `chdir` or add it to the argument of `fopen`. Bonus points for mentioning the problem of and solution for `~`.

Comment: @Jongware I just used the minimal approach, because by default it takes the current file path. Is there something wrong in my code, please tell me, because it works fine here in linux ubuntu.

Comment: OP mentioned "a file name and path", and it's unclear if OP knows how to combine them. My guess is OP does not, because *usually* there is no reason to mention 'file' and 'path' separately, and for 'filename' it is taken for granted that it *may* include a path. To help the OP, your example would be better if it showed where to insert, concat, or physically change to another path.

Comment: @Jongware Thanks, your advice was really good, I forgot to add the filepath, but now I've updated my answer and it looks better now.